Pandas: Combine 2 Rows If a Key Column is Empty
I have a dataframe:



Key
Name
Amount
Condition
Packing




A1
Candy A
25
Good
25 Nice


B1
Candy B
50
Good
49 Nice





Good
1 Damaged


C1
Candy C
40
Good
40 Nice



I want my dataframe to be like this: If the key column is empty, the row will be added into the nearest upper row with a key.



Key
Name
Amount
Condition
Packing




A1
Candy A
25
Good
25 Nice


B1
Candy B
50
Good,Good
49 Nice, 1 Damaged






(The entire empty row will be deleted)


C1
Candy C
40
Good
40 Nice



And then for the final, if the data is duplicate (Good,Good) I want it to be only showing 1 (Good),
Final Dataframe:



Key
Name
Amount
Condition
Packing




A1
Candy A
25
Good
25 Nice


B1
Candy B
50
Good
49 Nice, 1 Damaged


C1
Candy C
40
Good
40 Nice



Any Idea how to achieve this?
Edit:
I imported a data from a .ods file
            path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open ODS', os.getenv('HOME'), 'ODS(*.ods)')[0]
            all_data = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=range(1, 6))
            if all_data.size == 0:
                return
            print(all_data)

and then I tried fillna()
            all_data.fillna('', inplace = True)
            self.main_screen_product_tableWidget.setRowCount(all_data.shape[0])
            self.main_screen_product_tableWidget.setColumnCount(all_data.shape[1])
            self.main_screen_product_tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Key","Name",
            "Amount","Condition","Packing"])

This is how I show the data into QTableWidget
                for row in all_data.iterrows():
                    values = row[1]
                    for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                        tableItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                        self.main_screen_product_tableWidget.setItem(row[0], 
                        col_index, tableItem)
                


Is it possible that the Name or Amount columns also have different values than the row immediately above when the key is None, or duplicate values with the row immediately above?

Yes, It's Possible. Only the Key Column will not have the same value. Other column Might have same value like Condition Column.

Then what do you want to do with the Amount column? If the values in the Amount column are different from the row immediately above, do you want to convert the numeric values to strings and combine them with commas?

Ah right, you opened my mind. The File I imported, The Key will always have different name and amount value so I think there will be no problem. Like the row number three, if there is no key, there will be no name and amount value, only condition and packing. Thanks btw.

@HizaCrenata for better reproducibility of your data, you should provide a DataFrame constructor (see here). That would also allow to see how are your "empty" cells. Assuming df your example, could you [edit] the question and add the output of df.to_dict('tight')?.

Uhm, Allright I'll try.

You could use a custom aggregation function in groupby.agg:
def custom_agg(s):
    s = s.dropna().drop_duplicates()
    if len(s) > 1:
        return ', '.join(s.astype(str))
    return s

out = df.groupby(df['Key'].notna().cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(custom_agg)

NB. You could also use df['Key'].ffill() in place of df['Key'].notna().cumsum() as grouper.
If there is a possibility that you have multiple numeric values and want to handle them differently (e.g. getting the sum), you could use:
def custom_agg(s):
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(s):
        return s.sum()
    s = s.dropna().drop_duplicates()
    if len(s) > 1:
        return ', '.join(s.astype(str))
    return s

Output:
  Key     Name  Amount Condition             Packing
0  A1  Candy A    25.0      Good             25 Nice
1  B1  Candy B    50.0      Good  49 Nice, 1 Damaged
2  C1  Candy C    40.0      Good             40 Nice


Thanks for the answer, I'll try to do as you suggested. I'll need to do some trial and error first, so I need some time.

@HizaCrenata if your "empty" cells are not NaN (but for example empty strings), my above code won't work, in this case the grouper should be df['Key'].ne('').cumsum(). That's why a fully reproducible input is important, that removes these ambiguities.

When I first imported the file and then printed it, The output showme a NaN. Then I tried to use 'all_data.fillna('', inplace = True)' thus replace the NaN. Should I remove the 'df.fillna()? Thanks for the answer, I'll keep that in mind.

Yes, you should keep NaNs, not replace them with ''.

Allright, I'll do it. Thanks.

Thanks, I got many insight from your answer.

hello @mozway , I have a question, after out = df.groupby(df['Key'].notna().cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(custom_agg) some of the data return array([], dtype=object (if the column has 1 string and the other are NaN). It has blank array but when I run isnull(), it returned False.
I try to change it into NaN but can't change it. Any advice?

If i can describe it, I have a new Column named "Constraint" where A1 "No Sunlight" and others have NaN

nevermind, aldy get the answer!
